I cannot access flashcards package in ollama-python with a python 3 script. Where did I go wrong?
I tried to use flashcards package in ollama-python with a python 3 script.  Where did I go wrong?
How do you create an instance of Flashcards and append cards to the LaTeX package?
I tried the following:
with doc.create(Section('flashcards')):
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        flashcard_data = list(reader)

    for row in flashcard_data:
        questions = NoEscape(row[0])
        answer = NoEscape(row[1])
        doc.append(flashcards(question, answer))

What is missing or wrong?
